# Error: "Time inversion was detected in the trace" was observed in Windows Performance Analyzer (WPA)

Tags: windows, debugging, sdk, wpr

I made Windows performance recording of 15seconds on Windows 2k16 using Windows Performance Recorder(WPR) and when I tried to open the trace in WPA, I received the error ""Time inversion was detected in the trace". I tried multiple times and I get the same error.

I tried to re-record multiple times but I got the same error each time.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that downgrading the SDK from Windows 11 SDK (10.0.22621) to Windows 10 SDK, version 1803 (10.0.17134.12) fixed the problem for me. Older versions of windows SDK are available here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/

Comment: Did you downgrade WPR to fix the capture, or did you downgrade WPA to successfully analyze the ETL?

Comment: @kgibm I did not test with each. I used both WPA and WPR from the downgraded SDK.